# universal links when app is in background

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-universal-links

I'm working on adding universal links to my iOS app and I'm figuring things out but I'm a little lost on what to do when the app is not fully close, just running in the background.

when I debug through the app, it goes to `WillContinueUserActivity` then it goes to `ContinueUserActivity` which is fine and expected but I noticed in doing this that the previous screen the user was on is still visible during all of this, is that expected?

I'd prefer to have it seamlessly go to the desired screen and not have some jarring transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is expected and by design. You can't make those previous screens invisible programmatically.

Universal links will make the app open the desired page as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok that's pretty much what I needed to hear, Thanks